# How to get URL from HINTERNET handle

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook, wininet

I use wininet library and hook this to monitor internet requests.

The Hooking Function is "InternetConnectW", "HttpOpenRequestW" and "InternetReadFile".

First, I get a HINTERNET handle from "InternetConnectW".

And I get a second HINTERNET handle from "HttpOpenRequestW" with first handle.

When I hook "InternetReadFile", IN parameter include the second handle.

This is InternetReadFile Hooking Function.

```
BOOL
STDAPICALLTYPE
Hook_InternetReadFile(
__in HINTERNET hFile,
__out LPVOID lpBuffer,
__in DWORD dwNumberOfBytesToRead,
__out LPDWORD lpdwNumberOfBytesRead
)
{
    // i want to get Internet http URL here!!!!!

    return Origin_InternetReadFile(hFile, lpBuffer, dwNumberOfBytesToRead, lpdwNumberOfBytesRead);
}
```

How to get URL from HINTERNET handle?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `INTERNET_OPTION_URL` with [InternetQueryOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385101.aspx).

Example:

```
TCHAR *szUrl = new TCHAR[INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH];
DWORD dwLen = sizeof(TCHAR)*INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH;
BOOL bRet = InternetQueryOption(hFile, INTERNET_OPTION_URL, szUrl, &dwLen);
```

Comment: Is szUrl outbuffer allocated globally? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/windows/desktop/aa385101(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: where I dealloc szUrl?

Comment: Pointless to allocate a fixed length array in the heap, and wrong to use sizeof in that way. It gives you the size of the pointer not the buffer.